# Create dictionary with dynamic values in python

Tags: python-3.x

I want to create python dictionary something like below
{"Disk1" : "deva", "Disk2" :"devb" , "Disk3": "devc" .....}

How can I create the above dictionary without defining all vales statically

Comment: What is the pattern/input? Why do those keys map to those values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create an empty dictionary and add the keys/values later:

```
my_dict = {}

key = "abc"
value = 123

my_dict[key] = value
```

Answer (score 0):

Do the following :

```
def disck():
    g = {}
    for i in range(1,27):
        f = 'Disck'+str(i)
        j = 'dev'+ chr(97+i-1)
        g.update({f:j})
    return g
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know the `keys` in advance, it can be done as:

```
from collections import defaultdict
def add_to_dict(key, value, dict):
    dict[key] = value
    
out = defaultdict(str)
out['Disk1'] = ''
out['Disk2'] = ''
add_to_dict('Disk1', 'deva', out)
add_to_dict('Disk2', 'devb', out)
print (out)
```

Output:

```
defaultdict(<class 'str'>, {'Disk1': 'deva', 'Disk2': 'devb'})
```